# Convert Unsigned Int to Hexadecimal value

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, core-bluetooth

How can I convert a integer 6 digit number such as "1234674" to a hexadecimal 4 byte NSData in Objective-C ?

This is the part of our code that sends passkey:

```
#define HSL_PRIVATE_SERVICE_UUID 0xFF20 
#define HSL_PRIVATE_NEW_PASSKEY_UUID 0xFF35 
unsigned int newPassKey = [_confirmNewPassKey.text intValue];
NSLog(@"newPasskey %d", newPassKey);
NSData *d = [NSData dataWithBytes:&newPassKey length:sizeof(unsigned int)];
[_t writeValue:HSL_PRIVATE_SERVICE_UUID characteristicUUID:HSL_PRIVATE_NEW_PASSKEY_UUID p:_peripheral data:d];
```

I did an air capture comparing BTOOL versus iPhone passkey writes.

BTOOL (A simulator tool) wrote (the correct result) :

```
0x40e201
```

iPhone wrote(wrong data):

```
 0x0001e240
```

Not sure what is going on and how to fix it in the app so that the result matches what the Bluetooth device is expecting . I would like the result to be same as BTOOL one.

Comment: Your host endianness is not the same as the endianness of the protocol. You need `hton*` or `ntoh*` to convert.

Comment: I'm not sure how it works with NSLog but usually you can do it with the format string by using `%x` instead of `%d`. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string  -- Edit: Disregard. @Daniel Fischer answered it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
uint32_t value = [_confirmNewPassKey.text intValue];
uint32_t swapped = CFSwapInt32HostToBig(value);
NSData *d = [NSData dataWithBytes:&swapped length:sizeof(swapped)];
```

This assumes you want big endian for the output.